# 'User' object has no attribute <field-name> while adding new field in custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I have a custom User model which looks like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, validators=[alphanumeric])
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, validators=[alphanumeric])
    email = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, primary_key=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='+91')
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
document_status = models.CharField(default=set_default_doc_status, null=False, max_length=32)
```

Now i added a new field :

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

After that i run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

when i look into my db everthing seems to be alright. The new field is added to previous entries in the model but when i try to access the field in my code or in shell it give the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

I don't know why this error is coming even when the column exists in db.

```
>>> u=User.objects.get(username='a05')
>>> u.is_active
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

Comment: close and restart the server.

Comment: done that...not helped and it is also giving the same error in the shell when i try to access the field

Comment: Think you don't save User model to any other variable. Close the shell and then run it again.

Comment: No...i have checked it many times...tried restarting the server but error keeps coming

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @Shubham you already stored the User object inside a variable before updating the user model. That's why you got the above error. Now try `User.objects.get(username='a05').is_active`

Comment: @AvinashRaj actually i did that after updating my model.